# TypeScript observable object with Symbol.observable ponyfill

Tags: typescript, symbols

I'm trying to type an object that is observable and uses a custom `Symbol.observable` ponyfill (similar to the [`system-observable` ponyfill](https://github.com/benlesh/symbol-observable); code shown below), but I can't figure out a way to do it.

I've tried using `typeof $$observable` for the key and tried making `Symbol.observable` a `unique symbol`, but neither of those worked. I've had to resort to casting the object, but the problem with that approach is that I then have to cast the entire object (not shown below) and that makes it harder to catch other type errors due to other properties in the object being incorrectly typed. I also can't just do `ReturnType<typeof makeObservableContainer>` because I'd like to have it defined in a separate interface without having to depend on the function.

I would alternatively be interested in knowing if there's a way to cast it on a more fine-grained level than casting the entire object (if it turns out to be impossible to do without casting).

I've provided a playground link. Any help would be appreciated.

**First attempt** (no casting)

**Error message**

> Property '[Symbol.observable]' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: () => { [x: string]: ((observer: Observer) => { unsubscribe(): void; }) | (() => { [x: string]: ((observer: Observer) => { unsubscribe(): void; }) | ...; subscribe(observer: Observer): { ...; }; }); subscribe(observer: Observer): { ...; }; }; }' but required in type 'Container'.(2741)

**Code**

```
// system-observable.ts
declare global {
  interface SymbolConstructor {
    readonly observable: symbol
  }
}

const $$observable = /* #__PURE__ */ (() =>
  (typeof Symbol === 'function' && Symbol.observable) || '@@observable')()

export default $$observable

// observer-creator.ts
interface Observer {
    next(): void;
}

interface Observable {
    subscribe: (observer: Observer) => { unsubscribe(): void };
    [Symbol.observable](): Observable;
}

interface Container {
    // How do I type this?
    [Symbol.observable](): Observable;
}

function makeObservableContainer(): Container {
    // error here because this is not assignable to `Container`
    return {
        [$$observable]() {
            return {
                subscribe(observer: Observer) {
                    // TODO
                    return {
                        unsubscribe() {
                            // TODO
                        }
                    }
                },
                [$$observable]() { return this }
            }
        },

        // other properties that should conform to `Container` interface
    }
}
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEGcE9wFwUwLYFoD2AjccBOA3AhmgDZwB0M4AUACZwDGheWcoA5oenoaAN4WigBLAHbwsAMzy1mAZUgI0KQgGEUQ2FgCutGCiw8+-UEzxVVhSKHSZcBYgC4IchYQMBfCu4q1VsUABI-K2x8ImYAXlBgACpQAGIAfXiABQBVACUAUUTQKLAACjyASlAwgD4DPJhIAAc4FDFQWXlFErCIgHIxDSFtAVV20AAyQcanRRIgm1DigB8Z0HaAAUXJkOJ2wqKKCjgAD2rdGFAaCQ1CI4DV2zhtkEsMYOwkWmMdLDJKYVEJKVAAeQeuGw+kMoCEexgRQcOBQAioAG4PNsvtgfswAdY1sxeKDwBoMC8BGg4A48qtsA4MY8sMUyjxQN08QSsES4FDQDC4aBXIjQQBtJrOCaArEAXXZVKmxERnhR4kkzBUIjwwmBOMMdwAEigAO7HFCgACSoCqtRNAAsBOAAPwGfgCsaEYWY67iwqUkXXGXbLo9GB9ISgBB4ADWcElWKVMBV4Kw7KjMbVdsiYGwWF0oHN2GYxNoeA0mAtVsE4DBKCOeHA4AELCE1xNBoABgnVVhG8mmDANFhA+rQfbLp7Qm6Qf2x53u73k2Ox0zwITiWSRRT-suaaOZ5uNWAACp-AAif2nW-HcC7PY3J6vjPx85Zi+Kfavz-4dz3h+PL-77i-Y5-v9cAAaT8tz5QcXWHIp6QnC8YEtUt-xPRDv2AkC7nLLM9GqdNaiwf04FLOC8COcBzRQM4qFAbwhDEXQEAbUBm1UaNW0bQQRFRBVk3cdwgA)

---

**Second attempt** (unique symbol and a little bit of casting)

**Error**

> Type '() => { subscribe(observer: Observer): { unsubscribe(): void; }; observable: Observable; }' is not assignable to type '() => Observable'.
>     Property '[Symbol.observable]' is missing in type '{ subscribe(observer: Observer): { unsubscribe(): void; }; observable: Observable; }' but required in type 'Observable'.(2322)

**Code**

```
// system-observable.ts
declare global {
  interface SymbolConstructor {
    readonly observable: unique symbol
  }
}

const $$observable: SymbolConstructor['observable'] = /* #__PURE__ */ (() =>
  (typeof Symbol === 'function' && Symbol.observable) || '@@observable')() as SymbolConstructor['observable']

export default $$observable

// observer-creator.ts
interface Observer {
    next(): void;
}

interface Observable {
    subscribe: (observer: Observer) => { unsubscribe(): void };
    [Symbol.observable](): Observable;
}

interface Container {
    // How do I type this?
    [Symbol.observable](): Observable;
}

function makeObservableContainer(): Container {
    // error here because this is not assignable to `Container`
    return {
        [$$observable]() {
            return {
                subscribe(observer: Observer) {
                    // TODO
                    return {
                        unsubscribe() {
                            // TODO
                        }
                    }
                },
                [$$observable]() { return this }
            }
        },

        // other properties that should conform to `Container` interface
    }
}
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEGcE9wFwUwLYFoD2AjccBOA3AhmgDZwB0M4AUACZwDGheWcoA5oenoaAN4WigBLAHbwsAMzy1mAZUgI0KQgGEUQ2FgCutGCiw8+-UEzxVVhSKHSZcBYgC5QGoQICOG5lHmKDAXwp+KWlVYUAASUKtsfCI4B1kvZWCYTW1dAG0AckibGIyAXVAAXlBgACpQAGIAfSqABQBVACUAURrQUrAACk6ASiKAPgNOmEgABzgUMVB4hS5C+dAMsSdtAVUM0AAyTem5WZJs6OI+gB8TxYABC8PbOAye3tA8cF2ElTVkrR0sTJvcvIoFDgAA9RroYKAaBINIQIeE-sRASBLBgotgkLRjN8yJRhKIJFJQAB5VG4bD6QygIQgmC9Bw4FACKgAbn8gLx2AJzBJ1iOzF4lPAGgwmIEaFioE6h2wDh5aKwfUK-R4jjUwvAovFdNADKZoB8rMpaRmigOpL5eW1cpyxFZAQ54kkzHeMDwwnJAsMyIAEigAO6QlCgACSoBG4zDAAsBOAAPwGfjGvamhFwS09WXm252wHLISrVSgBB4ADWcGtfJdbupWG1Vfdek9-GR2CwulAkewzHFtDwGkwUZjgheQhQEOe4AELCEtzDQYABvWa-OE0Y4DANFghBTKYY0vCszF0zvd7umButyfT9ehSKsGK4FLzTLic+FVfr5+SmAACpEgAiRKrl+17npu25NiBUFOLeGr3lqfSQVByHfqAf6AcBKGnn4WHYZhIE+AANPhX77hEh7EMe3Brhe24wNGLw4VBTHYcRJHImOnZ6KMbbjFgMACHALz0XgELgJGKAwlQoBBEIYi6Agc6gIuqiug286CCInJOqufh+EAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you cast the `"@@observable"` string to `any`, you can type the `$$observable` as a unique symbol, which will let you use it as a key for the interfaces:

```js
const $$observable: unique symbol = /* #__PURE__ */ (() =>
    (typeof Symbol === 'function' && Symbol.observable) || ('@@observable' as any))();

export default $$observable

// observer-creator.ts
interface Observer {
    next(): void;
}

interface Observable {
    subscribe: (observer: Observer) => { unsubscribe(): void };
    [$$observable](): Observable;
}

interface Container {
    [$$observable](): Observable;
}
```